# Is there any way to find out full file path from another process?

Tags: c++, file, winapi, hook

recently I made the program which hooks the function "WriteFile" from notepad.exe.

I'd like to get the full path of the document which is hooked by my application, so I used

GetModuleFileName / GetModuleFileNameEx. However, the string only I could find is

'notepad.exe'

Regarding this situation, I'd like to ask you a question.

Is there any method to get documents' file name? like C:\Desktop\test.txt

Comment: Let's step back. Why are you trying to get the document path from Notepad? Hooking APIs is dangerous and unsupported. Maybe there's another solution to your problem that isn't as dangerous.

Comment: I found solution. I forgot the fact that I had already hooked the original function 'WriteFile'. I just catched its parameter 'HANDLE', and I could get the name of the document from it.

Comment: @Park What do you mean when you say "I found solution". What you describe is what my answer tells you to do.

Comment: I could not understand your answers then. Now I solved the problem by getting the parameters of the functions. Thanks for everyone to give me the comment.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I can't even begin to imagine the point of your program. It seems highly likely to me that there would be a better way to meet your actual goal.

But, taking the question at face value, if you have hooked `WriteFile` then presumably you could also hook `CreateFile`. If that's not an option, for whatever reason, then you can easily find the file name from your hooked WriteFile. Call [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953.aspx) passing `FileNameInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

If notepad received document's file name from command line, use [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: That won't work if Notepad was opened with a command-line parameter and then the user opened a different file in the same Notepad instance.